# json with hide and else if

Tags: json, if-statement, focusout

I am building a registration form. #onimg och #offimg are two divs with img. If you fill in an available user name the #offimg will show, and if you choose an allready taken username the #onimg vill show.

If you do not write anything at all in the registration field (like if you do delete the text) I want the images to hide. But they dont=(.

here is the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Username:</li>
    <li>Password:</li>
</ul>

<ul>

    <li><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="show" value="password">Show password</li>
</ul>

<div id="onimg"></div>
<div id="offimg"></div>


</fieldset>

<button type="button" id="reg" value="" >Register</button>
```

some css

```
#onimg {
  z-index:1000;
  position:absolute;
  left:300px;
  top:23px;
  background-image:url('notavailable.png');
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

#offimg {
  z-index:1000;
  position:absolute;
  left:300px;
  top:23px;
  background-image:url('available.png');
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

and here is the jquery

```
$('#user').focusout(function(){

  var users = $('#user').val();

  $.getJSON( "available.php" ,      //The URL to perform the lookup
     {name: users }, //The data you send
     function (result){     //The function to fire upon return
         if (!result) {       //result is JSON formatted
             $('#onimg').fadeIn('fast');
         } else  {
             $('#offimg').fadeIn('fast');
         }                                             
  });

});

$(function() {
    $('#user').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $("#onimge").hide();
            $("#onimge").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#user').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $("#onimge").hide(); // You misspelled #onimg
            $("#onimge").hide(); // This one should be #offimg, not a repeat of #onimg
        }
    });
});
```

BTW, you can do both images in one call:

```
$("#onimg, #offimg").hide();
```

You should also put the `$("#user").focusout()` handler inside the document ready function.

Comment: oh thanks. I fixed the name issu but still it fails. Do you mean I should put the focusout direct in beginning of my js file?

Comment: No, I mean it should be inside `$(function() {...}`.

Comment: uuuhm not really sure what part you ment I should put my code.

Comment: I don't know why you don't understand. You're doing it correctly for the `blur()` handler, it's inside the document ready handler function. The `focusout()` handler should be in that same block.